# Python question: CS Circles 7C Loops, Square Census

Tags: python

Coding Exercise: Square Census
The square numbers are the integers of the form K × K, e.g. 9 is a square number since 3 × 3 = 9. Write a program that reads an integer n from input and outputs all the positive square numbers less than n, one per line in increasing order. For example, if the input is 16, then the correct output would be

```
1
4
9
```

The answers are not posted on the site, and I cannot figure out how to write this one line of code.  Here is what I have so far

```
import math
n=int(input())
for i in range(1, n):
   if sqrt(i) // 0
   print i
```

Comment: The last two lines are not valid python. I don't know what `sqrt(i)//0` is supposed to do since division by `0` is not recommended. You could check if you get `i` when you square `int(sqrt(i))`

Comment: Thanks man, I should have put a note next to it like this, # trying to find the numbers where square root has remainder of zero.  Obviously that wasn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `math.pow()` to power the integers, instead of the square root with `math.sqrt()`. You could try something like this:

```
import math
n=int(input())
for i in range(1, n):
   if math.pow(i,2)<n:
    print(int(math.pow(i,2)))
```

Output with 16 as input

```
>>>1
>>>4
>>>9
```

Output with 26 as input

```
>>>1
>>>4
>>>9
>>>16
>>>25
```

Comment: Thanks man , that is a really good idea, square the numbers as they decrease, and if the total is less than n, print it.  excellent.

Comment: You're welcome man. I'll appreciate if you accept my answer, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to solve it and then figure out what they were actually trying to get me to learn, which was how to use breaks.  I added an if statement and this is what I got:

import math

n=int(input())

for i in range(1, n):

   if math.pow(i,2) < n:
      print(int(math.pow(i,2)))
   elif math.pow(i,2) > n:
      break

Comment: Yes, that is a nice modification.